# TypeScript: Accessing JQuery children as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I'm going through a porting exercise going from JavaScript to TypeScript and have hit the following issue.

In the original JavaScript code I've got:

```
var children = someJQueryElement.children('div');
var sortedChildren = children.sort(someSortFunction);
```

In TypeScript (1.4) all the jQuery methods return `JQuery` which isn't an `array` and therefore can't have `sort` called on it.

How should I go about solving this?

Comment: If you don't mind the simple change, you could do `var children = someJQueryElement.children('div').toArray();` and then `children` will have `sort`.

Comment: Your issue does not seem correct.  `.sort()` is a method of a jQuery object and that's why it works on a jQuery object.  Are you mistakenly compiling jQuery as if it were typescript code?

Comment: @jfriend00 `.sort()` is a `JavaScript` method on `Array` but feel free to offer an answer :)

Comment: jQuery has its own `.sort()` method.  It uses the Array `.sort()` in its implementation, but there is an actual `.sort()` method on a jQuery object.  This should not be a problem in typescript unless you are making some other error in how you are preparing jQuery.  `.sort()` is not a magic name in Javascript.  It's just a method name and lots of different types of objects can have a `.sort()` method.

Comment: jQuery doesn't expose a `sort` method, take a look at the source, so it isn't in the TypeScript Type Definition for it. Thanks for the extra intel though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change to a normal array using `.get()`

```
children.get().sort(someSortFunction);
```

Comment: The sorted array is passed back into a jQuery `append` operation which takes `any[]` so this works great (and it feels the least hacky).

Answer (score 2):

As an idea, have you tried to tell TypeScript to treat it as an array using casting?

```
var children = someJQueryElement.children('div');
var sortedChildren = (<Array>children).sort(someSortFunction);
```

This seems like a fairly tedious solution, though, if you have to do this in many places.  Hopefully someone has a better answer.

Comment: The usage of the sorted children beyond this code led me to Spokey's answer. It's good to see that you can still cast for Array functionality though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.slice.apply` to pass in the array-like object and convert it to a proper array.

```
var children = [].slice.apply(someJQueryElement.children('div'));
```

This is also a useful practice if you're not using jQuery but want to convert any other array-like objects, like `arguments`, for example.

Comment: You got an upvote from me. That tip on converting array-like objects is handy.

Comment: If I had to guess, you were downvoted for the unnecessary additional computation and potential performance hit.  That was my own issue with your answer, though I did not downvote.  The issue Tristan is facing is strictly compiler based though his code is correct, so adding in additional JavaScript instructions is unnecessary and potentially detrimental (albeit in a very small way).